# Writing an Array for running competition

Tags: java

> Write a program that asks for the names of three runners and the time, in minutes, it took each of them to finish a race. The program should display the names of the runners in the order that they finished.

I'm having a problem figuring out how to code this question, I'm facing issues arranging the times in ascending order then printing out the runner's names instead of their time.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class question2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int count = 3;
        int temp;
        
        double[] time = new double[count];
        double sum = 0;
        String[] names = new String[3];
        
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++);
            System.out.println("Enter your time");
        for (int i=1; i < names.length; i++);
            System.out.println("Enter your name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `RunTime` class with `name` and `time` fields. Prompt the user for names and times and build a `RunTime[]`. **Call `Arrays.sort()`**, and sort by time. Print the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a *Player* class having name and time. Then also make the class comparable by implementing the interface `Comparable`. Then override the methods `compareTo()` and `toString()` for comparison and proper output. Then have an array of Player objects, which can be sorted.

Check out the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
    public String name;
    public double time;

    public Player(String name, double time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %.2f", name, time);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Player o) {
        return (int) (this.time - o.time);
    }
}

public class question2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int count = 3;

        Player[] playerData = new Player[count];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name and time: ");
            playerData[i] = new Player(input.next().strip(), input.nextDouble());
        }

        Arrays.sort(playerData);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(playerData));
    }
}
```

Here I use `Arrays.sort()` which takes in the array and sort using the implemented `compareTo()` method of the *Player* class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
class Runner{
    String name;
    int time;
    public Runner(String name,int time){
        this.name=name;
        this.time=time;
    }
}

class SortByTime implements Comparator<Runner>{
    public int compare(Runner r1,Runner r2){
        return r1.time-r2.time;
    }
}
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      List<Runner> runners=new ArrayList<>();
      //input be like
      /*
        name1
        t1
        name2
        t2
      */
      while(sc.hasNext()){
        runners.add(new Runner(sc.nextLine(),sc.nextInt()));
        sc.nextLine();
      }
      Collections.sort(runners,new SortByTime());
      for(Runner ro:runners){
          System.out.println(ro.name);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's great that you've provided code that solves the OP's problem, please consider adding an explanation and/or comments to help the OP understand the code you've written.  They are going to need to understand the code in order to continue development, and besides, we should be helping people to learn from their mistakes, so they don't have to make so many posts in the future.  See @ahrooran's answer for an example of what I mean.